# Nextjs installing react using yarn by default

Tags: reactjs, next.js, yarnpkg

I'm installing a new react app using nextjs docs:

```
npx create-next-app
```

for some reason its using yarn by default:

[image]

I'm used to working with npm commands, how can I fix it please ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT:** `npx create-next-app my-app --use-npm`

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/10647

**OLD ANSWER:**
Remove `yarn.lock` and `node_modules/`

```
rm yarn.lock
rm -rf node_modules
```

install your dependencies with npm:

```
npm install
```

this will create a `package-lock.json` file, analogous to `yarn.lock`.

Comment: if i remove `node_modules`, wont it delete all the modules nextjs is using ? I've seen on youtube people using `npx ...` and the instalation used npm and not yarn..

Comment: Running `npm install` will read `package.json` and install the libraries listed in `dependencies`. Just don't delete `package.json`.

Comment: not working right.. I'm trying to understand why it's using yarn in the first place ..

Comment: It's intended. If you have yarn in your machine, it'll use that by default. I have edited the answer.

Comment: I am seeing the opposite behavior. I want yarn but npm is used by default.

Comment: Odd... maybe you don't have yarn in your PATH. create-next-app documentation is very clear: 

--use-npm - Explicitly tell the CLI to bootstrap the app using npm. Yarn will be used by default IF it's installed

Answer (score 1):

I tried the answer by @Rodrigo Amaral but faced several errors.

Before deleting the node_modules and yarn.lock, I ran npm install, which created a package-lock.json.

So the workflow is

```
npm install

rm yarn.lock

rm -rf node_modules

npm install
```

This should work.